# Strip powerpoint presentation of colors (fonts, bullets, number in lists, captions)

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, colors

I have powerpoint files with many many slides that do not meet the accessibility requirements for online teaching. I need to strip the colors off fonts, bullet points, list numbers, and parts of the captions.

what will be helpful is to replace the offending colors with a different color in all of the slides.

The thing is that the file won't let me select all the slides from the slide view panel on the left and make changes to anything. All the menu gets greyed out.

Is there any way to apply changes in color formats to all the slides in a presentation file? I'm using office 2007.

Any tips in accomplishing this is helpful. Thanks in advance.

I've uploaded the offending file here.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/5vf9um4wff4dkv2/shortened_Concepts_of_Biology_Chapter_01.pptx/file

Answer (score 0):

The presentation is not based on a theme or any other mechanism
with which one could change all the colors with several clicks.
The colors were modified inside the text manually, not by
applying a theme element, so they need to be changed manually
one by one.

A tool for making the work easier is
[Power-user](https://www.powerusersoftwares.com/),
a plugin for PowerPoint with a free trial version.
Its Black Friday offer is today at $112.50, but the free trial
version could be enough.
The feature to use is probably "Automate heavy formatting tasks".

If you are into using VBA, the following posts will start you
on the way:

- [Use VBA to change colors of slide elements in Powerpoint 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115072/use-vba-to-change-colors-of-slide-elements-in-powerpoint-2013)
- [PowerPoint VBA - loop all slides, all shapes, find chart, set datalabel color to Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929913/powerpoint-vba-loop-all-slides-all-shapes-find-chart-set-datalabel-color-to)

Comment: It's not mine. It's a file shared by a faculty from another school.

Comment: Sorry, I modifed the text to make it less personal.

Comment: How about this then? Is there a way to strip all bullets and lists from all of the slides in all the powerpoint files?

Comment: Power-user might be able to automate that.

Comment: I downloaded the free version, and there seems to be no way to do it. i did figure out using the slide master, i was able to change the colors, but it also changes font sizes, alignments etc so i have to manually changed them. it's such a pain.